# Issue with functions in program for C

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing

I am having a major issue with my functions for my program. I know it has to do with how I made my functions, but am not sure where the problem is. Please keep in mind that this is for an assignment for school and obviously I am lacking some understanding.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Define structure */

struct date 
{
    int day, month, year;
};

/* Function prototype */

int calc_date_number(struct date);

/* Begin Main */

 int main()
{
    /* Declare variable */

    struct date a;

    int valid=0, c;

    char *days[7] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    /* Issue greeting */

    printf("Welcome to the Date to Day-of-Week program. \n\n");
    printf("The program will give the day of the week for any date from 1/1/1900\n\n");

    /*Prompt user for date */

    do 
    {
        printf("Enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        scanf("%i/%i/%i", &a.month, &a.day, &a.year);

        /* Validate inputted date and re-prompt user for valid date */

        if(a.year>=1900 && a.year<=9999)
        {
            if(a.month>=1 && a.month<=12)
            {
                if((a.day>=1 && a.day<=31) && (a.month==1 || a.month==3 || a.month==5 || a.month==7 || a.month==8 || a.month==10 || a.month==12))
                valid = 1;
                else if((a.day>=1 && a.day<=30) && (a.month==4 || a.month==6 || a.month==9 || a.month==11))
                valid = 1;
                else if((a.day>=1 && a.day<=28) && (a.month==2))
                valid = 1;
                else if(a.day==29 && a.month==2 && (a.year%400==0 ||(a.year%4==0 && a.year%100!=0)))
                valid = 1;
                else
                printf("Invalid day. Please re-enter date.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Invalid month. Please re-enter date.\n");
            }
         }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid year. Please re-enter date. Year must be greater than 1900.\n");
        }
    }while(valid=0);

    /* Call function to calculate the number to represent the date */

    c = calc_date_number(a);

    /* Output date and day of the week */

    printf("%.2i/%.2i/%.2i falls on a %s\n\n", a.month, a.day, a.year, days[c]);
    printf("Thank you for using the Date to Day-of-Week program.");

    return 0;
}/* end of main */

/* Begin function calc_date_number */

  int calc_date_number(struct date d)
{
    int f, g, n;
    long long n1, n2;

    /* Establish the calculation for N1 1/1/1900 */

    n1 = (1461 * 1899) / 4 + (153 * 15) / 5 + 1;

    /* Establish the calculation for f and g for N2 calculation */

    if (d.month <= 2)
    {
        f = d.year- 1;
    }
    else
    {
        f = d.year;
    }

    if(d.month <= 2)
    {
        g = d.month + 13;
    }       
    else 
    {
        g = d.month + 1;
    }

    /* Calculate N2 for inputted date */

    n2 = (1461 * f) / 4 + (153 * g) / 5 + d.day;

    /* Calculate numeric day of the week */

    n =(n2 - 621049) % 7;

    return n;

} /* end of function */
```

My Output is 
Welcome to the Date to Day-of-Week program.

The program will give the day of the week for any date from 1/1/1900

Enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): 09/24/1994
Invalid year. Please re-enter date. Year must be greater than 1900.
00/1961062381/6356776 falls on a Monday

Thank you for using the Date to Day-of-Week program.

Comment: What *is* the "issue"? Do you get build errors? Then copy-paste the full and complete build output into the question, and add a comment in the code on the lines where you get errors. Or if you get unexpected results, show the actual and expected output (for some specified input). Also please read or refresh [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Your functions are declared as returning integers, yet they contain no `return` statement. Go back to your book/lecture notes and revisit the section about functions.

Comment: The `do { … }while(valid=0);` loop doesn't repeat, does it?  Assignment vs comparison!  Using `void main(int c)` is just wrong — `int main(void)` is appropriate here.   You need to define `c` in your code, and then assign the result of the function to it.  And the `/* Call to main to receive numeric day */ main(c);` at the end is bizarre!  That's not how you do it.  You use `return c;`!

Comment: you need to edit your question and tell us: 1) What is the program supposed to do and 2) what problem do you have.

Comment: To summarize: It seems like you're mostly guessing about things and how C works. That's not really a good way to learn any language, programming or written/spoken. Invest in a couple of beginner books, read a few tutorials online, take a class or perhaps a few paid courses online. There's no shortcut to learn programming or a language, except hard work and studying.

Comment: I have used the improvements that Eraklon showed me and can understand the major issues my program had. Currently, the issue I am having is that my validation and the ending printf results are bogus with the revisions. I have updated the code and included my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues like

- Functions not returning anything
- Using void as return value for the  main function (possible, but not 
  advised)
- Calling the main function  (it possible, but not advised)
- In `printf("%.2i/%.2i/%.2i falls on a %s\n\n",a.month, a.day, a.day, 
  days[c]);` you write `a.day` instead  of `a.year` as 4th argument.

This one seems to work, although I did not validate your calculation of the dates.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Define structure */

struct date 
{
    int day, month, year;
};

/* Function prototype */

int calc_date_number(struct date);

int calc_day_number(long long);


/* Begin Main */
int main()
{
    /* Declare variable */
    struct date a;
    long long c;
    int valid=0;

    char *days[7] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    /* Issue greeting */
    printf("Welcome to the Date to Day-of-Week program. \n\n");
    printf("The program will give the day of the week for any date from 1/1/1900\n\n");

    /*Prompt user for date */
    do 
    {
        printf("Enter date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        scanf("%i/%i/%i", &a.month, &a.day, &a.year);

        /* Validate inputted date and re-prompt user for valid date */

        if(a.year>=1900 && a.year<=9999)
            if(a.month>=1 && a.month<=12)
                if((a.day>=1 && a.day<=31) && (a.month==1 || a.month==3 || a.month==5 || a.month==7 || a.month==8 || a.month==10 || a.month==12))
                    valid = 1;
                else if((a.day>=1 && a.day<=30) && (a.month==4 || a.month==6 || a.month==9 || a.month==11))
                    valid = 1;
                else if((a.day>=1 && a.day<=28) && (a.month==2))
                    valid = 1;
                else if(a.day==29 && a.month==2 && (a.year%400==0 ||(a.year%4==0 && a.year%100!=0)))
                    valid = 1;
                else
                    printf("Invalid day. Please re-enter date.\n");
            else
                printf("Invalid month. Please re-enter date.\n");
        else
            printf("Invalid year. Please re-enter date. Year must be greater than 1900.\n");
    } while(valid=0);

    /* Call function to calculate the number to represent the date */
    c = calc_date_number(a);

    /* Output date and day of the week */
    printf("%.2i/%.2i/%.2i falls on a %s\n\n", a.month, a.day, a.year, days[c]);
    printf("Thank you for using the Date to Day-of-Week program.");

    return 0;
}/* end of main */

/* Begin function calc_date_number */

int calc_date_number(struct date d)
{
    int f, g;
    long long n1, n2;

    /* Establish the calculation for N1 1/1/1900 */
    n1 = (1461 * 1899) / 4 + (153 * 15) / 5 + 1;

    /* Establish the calculation for f and g for N2 calculation */
    if (d.month <= 2)
        f = d.year- 1;
    else
        f = d.year;

    if(d.month <= 2)
        g = d.month + 13;
    else 
        g = d.month + 1;

    /* Calculate N2 for inputted date */
    n2 = (1461 * f) / 4 + (153 * g) / 5 + d.day;

    /* Call function to calculate the day number */
    return calc_day_number(n2); // you could just do return (n2 - 621049) % 7 and get rid of calc_day_number function

} /* end of function */

/* Begin function calc_day_number */
/* Calculate numeric day of the week */
int calc_day_number(long long n2)
{
    return (n2 - 621049) % 7;
} /* end of function */
```

Comment: I have updated my code with your revisions. I did tweak it since I want a normal integer and not a long integer for the character string array. My issue is that the validation and results are not working properly. Initially, the validation worked properly.

Comment: Can you give an example input and output where it is not worked properly?

Comment: I have an example up in my post.  So I input 09/24/1994, and it said the year is incorrect. Then when it should output the date entered, it printed 00/1961062381/6356776 and the wrong day.

Comment: My professor got back to me. The problem was my scanf and inputs. I can't put 0 before a number with %i and so i changed them to %d  and it works now. Thank you so much for your help and tolerance!

Comment: @ubutom Glad if it helped.